# Some combinatorial properties of Fano geometry

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, symmetry, noneuclidean-geometry

I am starting to learn about finite geometries and in particular am trying to understand some basic (mainly combinatorial) features of the seven point geometry.

(I have not yet reached the context of projective geometry, so my questions are truly basic, and I'd appreciate answers that use only elementary methods.)

[image]

Let's say that a symmetry is a permutation of $\{1, \ldots, 7\}$ that preserves lines. **I am not sure how to prove whether or not the following properties hold**:

(i) Given any two different lines (e.g., $\{1, 3, 2\}$ and $\{3,6,5\}$), there is a symmetry that takes one to the other.

(ii) Given any two distinct points, there is a symmetry taking one to the other.

**Moreover, although I am able to see why there are 168 total symmetries, I can't see why there are 24 symmetries fixing a point and 24 fixing a line (as stated on WIkipedia).  I also can't figure out at all how many would fix two lines.**

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me answer these questions. My intuition with finite geometry is pretty weak right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question (i) it suffices to show that for any line, there is a symmetry taking the line $\{1,2,3\}$ to that line. There are only six other lines, so this is a matter of enumeration.

For question (ii) it suffices to show that for any point, there is a symmetry taking the point $\{1\}$ to that point. There are only six other points, so this is a matter of enumeration.

As for the 24 symmetries fixing a point; again for concreteness sake let's say the point $\{1\}$ is fixed. Then $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$ and $\{4\}$ are not on a line. Let $\{p\}$ and $\{q\}$ be such that $\{1\}$, $\{p\}$ and $\{q\}$ are not on a line. Show that there exists a symmetry fixing $\{1\}$ and mapping $\{2\}$ to $\{p\}$ and $\{4\}$ to $\{q\}$. Show that this determines the symmetry entirely, because symmetries preserve lines.

This is a lot of work and it is very far from insightful. I suggest you follow the more natural approach suggested by Mikhail Katz, which also generalizes much, much better to other finite geometries.

Comment: Why are these sufficient?

Comment: Because a composition of symmetries is again a symmetry, and the inverse of a symmetry is again a symmetry. So you can map any line to any line by first mapping it to this specific line, and then to whatever line you like. The same for points.

Comment: Yes, but we still need to show that any line can be mapped to $\{1, 2,3\}$.

Comment: That is done by taking the inverse of a symmetry mapping $\{1,2,3\}$ to that line.

Comment: So it would also help to show that this set of symmetries is a group; something that is also immediate when viewing the Fano plane as the projective plane over $\Bbb{F}_2$.

Comment: Can we say anything about uniqueness of the symmetry in properties (i) and (ii)?

Comment: The 24 symmetries fixing a point tell you exactly how non-unique the symmetry in property (ii) is, and the symmetry in property (i) is similarly non-unique. This similarity is immediate by duality.

Comment: Sorry, but why exactly does this tell us that it's not unique? I don't see it.

Comment: For any point, there are precisely 24 symmetries fixing that point. So if you have a symmetry taking a point $p$ to a point $q$, then composing it with one of the 24 symmetries fixing $q$ yields another symmetry taking $p$ to $q$. Again this is a very simple application of group theory. I strongly suggest you get familiar with basic linear algebra and group theory as a means to study such finite geometries.

Answer (score 2):

To do calculations with the Fano plane it is convenient to work with a more natural model provided by homogeneous coordinates in $F^3$ where $F$ is the field with $2$ elements.  Here a point can be either thought of as a line through the origin, or the equivalence class of points in $F^3\setminus\{0\}$ under the relation of being proportional by a nonzero scalar in $F$. Then numbers of symmetries, etc. can be calculated using subgroups of the linear group over the field $F$.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. However, I am just trying to build some very basic intuition at this point, so I am looking to solve my problems by very direct, elementary methods.

Comment: The elementary presentation of the Fano geometry that you gave is fine for being concrete, but the point is that it masks the symmetries that are helpful in order actually to compute something.  These calculations lead you to appreciate the advantages of the model in homogeneous coordinates. @CuriousKid7

Comment: I'll keep this in mind for the future, but I'd still like to be as concrete as possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

To give simple answers

I) you know that there are 168 symmetries in total $168 / 7 =24 $ is the number is symmetries that leave the $1$ on its place (one of these symmetries is the identity)

Most times there is more than one symmetry that does what you describe

I haven't counted them but I think that for 2 fixed points there are 4 symmetries that leaves two points fixed but $8$ if you also count the symmetries that exchanges the points.

For symmetries that leave a line fixed a symmetry that swaps  points on the line does count as symmetry that fixes the line

Hopes this helps

Was puzzling just for a start enumerate (write them all down)  all symmetries where point $1$ stays on the  first spot

Then all where point $3$ stays on the third spot

Looks a lot of tedious work but is quite simple and enlightening

Then for symmetries that have some qualities you can just check the ones in your list and count them

For example symmetries that fix two lines: 
Suppose line 123 and 356

point 3 is then fixed 
Just count in your list of symmetries where a 3 is on the third spot ,the ones where on the first second fifth and sixth spots are a 1 2 5 and a 6 .

Be aware you will run into some philosophical questions  and there is the learning really happens

Good luck